# Convert stream of map to HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have class structure similar to

```
@Data    
class Permission
    {
      String id;
      Map<String,String> roles;
    }
```

I am having such `List<Permission>` permissions and I am trying to get `Map<String,String>` roles from this `List` using `streams` by doing something like:

```
permissions.stream().
                .map(Permission::getRoles) //it is giving me Stream<Map<String,String>>
                .collect()  //How to collect to Hashmap ?
```

So that I can further iterate over this map to get `Set<String>` containing all the keys of this `Hashmap`. In brief, the goal is to:

1. get Permission object from this List
2. then get `Map` from this Object
3. and then put keys of all this `Map` objects into `Set<String>` keys such that it'll have all the keys of `Map` objects from step(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the keys of all the Maps in a set

You can do it like this.

- stream the permissions
- flatten the streams of each map's keyset.
- collect to a Set

```
Set<String> keys = permissions.stream()
        .flatMap(permission -> permission.getRoles().keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

According to the documentation, the mutability of `toSet()` isn't guaranteed.  If you want to create an instance of the the API's `HashSet` you can replace the above collector with: 
`.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));`

Note that regardless of the set implementation, duplicate keys will be discarded.